# Search - handle natively or make an API call? (Android, Node.JS, MongoDB Backend)

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, node.js, mongodb

I am building a mobile-only **ecommerce** application (Android app for now) which would display a list of events to the users. These events can/will change daily.

The landing page of the app would make the following API call to the Node.JS server to retrieve today's events (<500 I presume):

```
/get/events
```

Now, I want to implement a **search functionality** on my mobile application. There are two ways of going about it (I guess):

1. Handle the search on the Android Application by using the local DB of the Android App (this would help me implement the Autocomplete functionality)
2. When a user types a query string, make an API call to the server to retrieve the list of relevant results. This API call would find results from the MongoDB (textsearch functionality) and return them in a JSON format to the Android Applicatio e.g.:

`/get/search?q='Festival'`

Also, I would have to implement filters as well (e.g. music, drama, comedy etc) so I have the same question for that as well (handle in Android or API call).

Which of the above is the preferred approach? Would be of great great help to know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but it sounds like you have these requirements:

- node.js-based backend tool that will let you easily connect to your existing mongodb database
- search/query records through a REST API
- return results in JSON format

The [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) framework does all of those things out-of-the-box. If you define your model definitions for your database, you won't need to write any custom logic to enable searching and filtering of your data through the REST API.

Getting started with sails.js is easy, even if you don't know node.js. Check out the [SailsCast](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/20/building-a-sails-application-ep1-installing-sails-and-create-initial-project) videos to see if sails.js is right for you. If you have questions, sails.js has live community support in Gitter: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I shall have a look at Sails.js. The reason I asked my question is that I would need to implement AutoComplete on the client side for Search functionality. If a user types in 'Fest' , he gets all the events containing 'Festival' in real-time. Would it make sense to have the server responsible for this real-time search or the client itself?

Comment: sails.js can easily handle this. You can search for a partial string, and return the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately a decision you'll have to make based on the amount of time you have to put in and server load requirements.

Leaving the search functionality to the server is often the simplest solution as you only have to deal with database lookups in one place. Also depending on the application, you would only need to send a small subset of the available data instead of everything. However, if you plan on getting a large number of requests frequently, this could exhaust your server's resources.

Since you only sync data once per day, it may be worth considering your local database approach. This will take more thought to implement, since you'll need to worry about retrieving new data, populating a local database, and implementing search on every device. If your search functionality ever changes, users will need to update their app in order for changes to take affect. Also, if you have a large number of users, you may need to consider staggering daily retrievals to prevent too many requests to the server at once.

Comment: I would need to implement AutoComplete on the client side for Search functionality. If a user types in 'Fest' , he gets all the events containing 'Festival' in real-time. Now this can be done either on the Server/Client. Initially I wouldn't worry much about server load, but going forward, there might be a lot of requests pouring to the server. But I am looking for a medium-long term solution.